# In C combine numbers and get the numbers inside without logical operators

Tags: c, modulo

Problem info

[image: 1]

Any use of logical operators, relational operators, bool variables, or selection constructs is prohibited

I tried creating the number like this:

```
int year_diff = grad_year - start_year;
int prog_years = year_diff % 100;
int uniq_id = student_id % 10000;
int id_num = start_year * 100000000 + program_num * 1000000 + prog_years * 10000 + uniq_id;
```

and pulling out those numbers like this

```
int loc_diff = loc2 - loc1;
int div = pow(10, loc1 - 1);
int desired_digits = (id_num / div) % (int) pow(10, loc_diff + 1);
```

but it is not working and I am having a really hard time. Can someone help

Comment: Use a *string* for the ID, with its components, and try to avoid `pow()` with integers. Don't be misled by the term "number". With phone, house address, and credit card "numbers" these are not integers.

Comment: The important realization is that when humans say numbers, they don't always mean numbers in the literal mathematical sense. A phone number is not really a number, it's a string. And so is your student ID. Humans call number everything that has digits. In software, numbers are things on which to perform mathematical calculations. Adding some constant number to phone numbers or student ids doesn't make sense (as evidence that they're not really numbers). So what are they? They're strings.

Comment: Also, regarding `int` - depending on your platform and compiler settings, `int` may be 16 bits or 32 bits. Either way, `int` is too small for 12 digits anyway. You would need to use `long` and ensure that it is large, for example, using `static_assert(sizeof(long) > 4)` (requires `<assert.h>`) or using `static_assert(MAX_LONG > 999999999999);` (requires `<limits.h>`). Or `uint64_t`. But better try `snprintf()` to solve this problem.

Comment: @ChristianHujer advise `long long` or `int64_t` because `long` can be (and in MSVC it *is*) the same size as `int`. I can't see any reason *ever* to use `long`, for any purpose.

Comment: @WeatherVane You're right, thanks for correcting me where I was wrong. `int64_t` or `uint64_t` - or `long long` to be safe, but not `long`. `long long` is on the safe side (or not supported, but when it's not supported, one is most likely out of luck anyway).

Comment: @ChristianHujer, @WeatherVane: Using  `int64_t, uint64_t, long long, long` type for `id_num` is not certainly sufficient.  The right hand side of the `=` also should use certain wider math.

Comment: @WeatherVane Agree `long`, not that useful, yet it has corner case uses:  under 2G file seeking and reporting, when converting _strings_ to `long` or narrower types, rounding in range FP values to `long` or narrower types, less ponderous to use than `int_least32_t` when min 32-bit needed in portable code.   Alternatives, though more complex, exist.  Perhaps a good SO question?

Answer (score 2):

- Make certain the right-hand side of the `=` uses wide enough math.  OP's code, as is, may risk `int` overflow.  `int` is not certainly wide enough for 12 decimal digit math.  `long long` good for at least 18 decimal digits.
- Assign the result to a wide enough type too.  Use `long long` constants to coax the math into `long long`.

```
// int id_num = start_year * 100000000 + program_num * 1000000 + prog_years * 10000 + uniq_id;
long long id_num = start_year*100000000LL + program_num*1000000LL + prog_years*10000LL + uniq_id;

...
// int desired_digits = (id_num / div) % (int) pow(10, loc_diff + 1);
long long desired_digits = (id_num / div) % (long long) pow(10, loc_diff + 1);
```

- Consider an integer alternative to `pow()`. `pow()` risks being "off-by-1" or more when converted to an integer type.  Avoid floating point math for an integer problem.

```
// I assert this code also fulfills
// "Any use of logical operators, relational operators, bool variables, ... is prohibited"
// It may/may not also fulfill "or selection constructs".  Unclear what OP means by that.
// If `"selection" means `if, switch, _Generic`, then code does not use those.

long long ipowll(int base, unsigned exponent) {
  long long ibase = base;
  long long ipower = 1;
  while (exponent) {
    // This abbreviated code here does not check or prevent overflow.
    // Added tests needed for that.
    ipower *= (long long[2]) {1, ibase}[exponent % 2];
    ibase *= ibase;
    exponent /= 2;
  }
  return ipower;
}
```

- Since task does not use signed values, consider using `unsigned` and `unsigned long long`.

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned long long upow(unsigned x)
{
    unsigned long long result = 1;
    while(x--) result *= 10;
    return result;
}

unsigned long long getID(unsigned sNum, unsigned yStart, unsigned yEnd, unsigned programe)
{
    return (yEnd - yStart) * upow(4) + 
           sNum + 
           (programe % 100) * upow(6) + 
           (yStart % 10000) * upow(8);
}

unsigned long long extract(unsigned long long num, unsigned start, unsigned end)
{
    num /= upow(start - 1);
    num %= upow(end - start + 1);
    return num;
}


int main(void)
{
    unsigned long long id = getID(1234, 2020, 2024, 78);
    printf("%llu\n", id);
    printf("%llu\n", extract(id, 4, 7));
}
```

You need to add some parameter checks (to see if they are valid)

Comment: I like the `% 100` and `% 10000` to limit  range - UV.  Could also use a `% limit` with `yEnd - yStart` and `sNum`.